# OpenDialog disappears while running my program

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-6, topendialog

I'm using Borland C++Builder 6.

`TOpenDialog` disappears while running my program.

What can be the reason?

Which property on the form\open dialog is responsible for this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Dialogs do not just *disappear*. Either it was intentionally closed, or it is probably hidden behind your main window. Unfortunately the VCL in BCB6 suffers from z-order issues, which were fixed in later versions. Try calling [`GetOpenFileName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646927.aspx) directly so you can provide an owner window to avoid any z-order problems.